# SQL Query to get ToTime where max(EndMeasDepth) and min(ReportNo) and Min(SeqNo)

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

Please help.  The query is as far as I can get.  Here is the query in txt format.  Since the max(EndMeasDepth) is NULL or 0, I want to get the column [ToTime] with min(ReportNo) and min(SeqNO)

```
select D.wellid, min(ToTime) as [ToTime]from 
DailyOperations d
INNER JOIN (select WellID, max(ISNULL(EndMeasDepth,0)) AS MaxEndMeasDepth 
from DailyOperations Group By WellID) DM on DM.WellID = D.WellID and 
DM.MaxEndMeasDepth = ISNULL(D.EndMeasDepth,0)
where D.JobID ='Drilling' and D.wellid ='102193.01'
GROUP BY D.WellID
order by D.WellID
```

Answer (score 0):

First we find the min and max values and then get the data.

```
WITH dMax AS
(
    SELECT 
        WellID          =   d.WellID
    ,   EndMeasDepth    =   ISNULL(MAX(d.EndMeasDepth), 0)
    ,   ReportNo        =   MIN(d.ReportNo)
    ,   SeqNo           =   MIN(d.SeqNo)
    FROM
        DailyOperations AS d
    WHERE   1 = 1   --if needed
    --  AND d.JobID ='Drilling' 
    --  AND d.wellid ='102193.01'
    GROUP BY
        d.WellID
)
SELECT
    WellID  =   d.WellID
,   ToTime  =   d.ToTime
FROM
                DailyOperations AS d
    LEFT JOIN   dMax            AS dm   ON  dm.WellID = d.WellID
                                        AND dm.EndMeasDepth = ISNULL(d.EndMeasDepth, 0)
                                        AND dm.ReportNo = d.ReportNo
                                        AND dm.SeqNo = d.SeqNo
```